# Scroll top does not equal as moving blocks up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make some 2d game with javascript, html and css.

This is just a start but it seems like I have some weird problem.

When I move up I move my player block up and scroll top but scroll top is scrolling more then player block moved.

I am getting player block position to move up with 50px and document scrollTop position to move up same 50px by subscription.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 //map info
 var $map = $('#map'),
  viewportWidth = +$(window).width(),
  viewportHeight = +$(window).height(),
  mapWidth = +$map.width(),
  mapHeight = +$map.width();
 
 //player info
 var $player = $('.player').eq(0);

 //Adding some logic
 //Half height and width of map and half of viewport to center it

 var halfMW = mapWidth / 2,
  halfMH = mapHeight / 2,
  halfVW = viewportWidth / 2,
  halfVH = viewportHeight / 2;

 //Now we need to get subsrtiction of half map width and half viewport width 
 //and same for height

 var mapPositionX = halfMW - halfVW,
  mapPositionY = halfMH - halfVH;

 //Now we need to put map in negative values so the viewport stands in the center

 //Css example
 /*
 $map.css({
  'top': '-' + mapPositionY + 'px',
  'left': '-' + mapPositionX + 'px'
 });
 */
 //Scroll example
 $(document).scrollLeft(mapPositionX);
 $(document).scrollTop(mapPositionY);

 //moving player

 $(document).keydown( function(key) {
  console.log(key.which);
  //down - 40
  //right - 39
  //up - 38
  //left - 37

  if(key.which === 38) {
   var posUP = +$player.css("top").replace("px", "");
   $player.css('top', posUP-50+'px');
   $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() - 50);
  }
 }); 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#map {
 width: 10000px;
 height: 10000px;
 background: #71D014;
 position: relative;
 overflow: scroll;
}

.blocks {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 4950px;
 left: 4950px;
 background: orange;
}

.player {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5050px;
 left: 5050px;
 background: #005ED2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Tanks</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map">
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="player"></div>
 </div>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, consider reformulating your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Hmm, what is unclear here specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem.

Well ***up, down, left and right arrows*** on keyboard are set as defaults for moving `scroll x and y` and I just needed to add `preventDefault();` on start.